# NextJS 13/14 Server Components + Installable PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, next.js13, react-server-components

I am brand new in the NextJS world - and react frameworks too for that matter. Coming from backend / server-rendered HTML web development.

I am confused as to the relationships between a PWA, and NextJS server components vs. client components. My naive first thought would be that a PWA should essentially be client-side only (i.e. the JS bundle gets installed and the app runs fast from there on out), and therefore should only leverage client-rendered components.

But I'm seeing in a few places (seems hard to Google this topic with most of the web content being circa 2021/2022 with old NextJS) that server components are good for PWAs.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0):

[Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) are rendered at request time and cached if possible, the only thing that is returned from a server component is static html and maybe one-or-many server or client components. Inside your PWA both component types would have the following roles:

---

###### Server Components

Provide the layout and static markup for your application, something like a header or navigation that does not need interactivity from the user. Also are [suited for](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#benefits-of-server-rendering) data fetching needs from a database, API or similar. These requests can also be cached.

###### Client Components

Are used to collect user input, listen to events and use hooks. By default everything is rendered on the server and you can opt-in to client components with `"use client"` the the top of your file.

---

By using server components where possible you can reduce the size of your client bundle to a minimum what will make your PWA even faster than it was before. On a very basic level you can think of server components as of a handlebars template on steroids.